# How to set the main class classpath for JavaExec task in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, classpath

I got that if I want to run a main from a Main class, by using the `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` classpath, I have to put the Main class inside of `src/main/java` and use something like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {

}

task myTask (type: JavaExec){
    dependsOn classes
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'Main'
}
```

What I want is understand how I can specify a different classpath from which to retrieve the class containing the main(). 
What if I want to run the main from a class which is not in src/main/java but it is in the same folder as the `build.gradle`?

I'm aware that it has no sense to do something like that, but I wish to find a solution **as an exercise** to learn Gradle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you still need to compile such class and in the case the class is not in the standard `src/main/java` directory, **you will need to define additional `SourceSet` to that path and use the same approach as you described**:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        custom {
            srcDirs = ['custom/path']
        }
    }
}

task myTask (type: JavaExec){
    dependsOn classes
    classpath sourceSets.custom.runtimeClasspath
    main = 'Main'
}
```

Comment: Would this setup add the files from the custom path to the final `.jar` file?